# Clojure tokenizer

Tags: parsing, clojure

Please review the following Clojure tokenizer. The goal is to study Clojure, so sometimes I re-implement functions (it will be nice to see standard functions for this). Beyond of this, code seems quite cumbersome.

```
(defn space? [^Character c]
 (Character/isWhitespace c))

(defn digit? [^Character c]
  (= (Character/getType c)
     (Character/DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER)))

(defn to-int [ds]
  (reduce #(+ (* 10 %1) %2) (map #(- (int %) (int \0)) ds)))

(defn take-int [s]
  (when (digit? (first s))
    (let [[digits rs] (split-with digit? s)]
      [rs {:int (to-int digits)}])))

(defn take-sym [s]
  (case (first s)
    \+ [(rest s) {:sym :plus}]
    \- [(rest s) {:sym :minus}]
    \* [(rest s) {:sym :star}]
    \/ [(rest s) {:sym :slash}]
    nil))

(defn take-error [msg]
  [nil {:error msg}])

(defn tokens [expr]
  (loop [ex expr, ts []]
    (let [nsp (drop-while space? ex)]
      (if (empty? nsp)
        (conj ts {:eof nil})
        (if-let [[rs t] (or (take-int nsp)
                            (take-sym nsp)
                            (take-error (str "Invalid symbol " (first nsp))))]
          (if (:error t)
            t
            (recur rs (conj ts t))))))))

(defn -main [& args]
  ; Work around dangerous default behavior in Clojure.
  (alter-var-root #'*read-eval* (constantly false))

  (println (tokens (seq " 20 + 32 * 4 ")))
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you're still at it (given it's been a few months) ; in any case, here's my answer (it could be useful to someone, who knows).

- speaking of standard functions, maybe you could leverage the Clojure reader e.g.:

  ```
  (def to-int (comp read-string #(apply str %)))
  ;; the str bit is ugly, but necessary (read-string consumes Strings)
  ```

  Depending on what you're attempting to do, you could parse your chain of characters directly into a stream of Clojure symbols, data structures and basic types or use it more precisely, like above.

  Otherwise, you could save yourself the trouble of reimplementing integer parsing in `to-int` by using `Integer/parseInt` on the substring directly.
- performance-wise, `char` sequences consume a lot of memory (even lazy ones), not to mention the risks of holding onto heads ; you should consider using `String` manipulation techniques over sequences: `subs` over `rest`/`next`, regular expressions over `split-with`/`drop-while`, etc. .

  - for example, `drop-while space?` screams `trim`, `ltrim` or `(subs (re-find "\S" ...) ...)`.
  - `when (digit? (first ...))`/`split-with digit?` would become `when-let [[_ digits rs] (re-find "^(\d+)(.*)$" ...)]`
- BTW -assuming input is big- feeding the whole input to the lexer feels like a waste of memory ; you should instrument a `Reader` or something, and tokenize as you read.
- `-main`: if you don't use `read-string`, you don't need your `*read-eval*` bit ; besides, `alter-var-root` is not the way to do it: local rebinding is (e.g. with `binding`).
- `tokens`: sequence returning function using `loop`/`recur` with an accumulator screams `lazy-seq`:

  ```
  (defn tokens [expr]
    (lazy-seq
      ...
        (if (empty? nsp)
          [{:eof nil}]
            ...
              (cons t
                (if-not (:error t)
                  (tokens rs)))
  ```

  The only difference in behaviour is with errors, that get appended last instead of returned directly, which feels more flexible (the lexer stops on an error token instead of returning an error token) ; a test for errors would become `(:error (last ...))` instead of `(:error ...)`.
- `take-sym` : this `case` screams hashmap to me and all those `first`/`rest` call for a little destructuring ; what about:

  ```
  (def char->sym {\+ :plus
                  \- :minus
                  \* :star
                  \/ :slash})

  (defn take-sym [[c & r]]
    (if-let [sym (char->sym c)]
      [r {:sym sym}]))
  ```

  AFAIK `case` performs comparisons based on hash code, so it should have the same (poor) performance as a hashmap. If it becomes a performance bottleneck, you may choose to reimplement it on the Java side (as a `switch` statement) or use a `char`-keys optimized map instance (like [this one](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/chars/Char2ObjectMap.html) from [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) or [that one](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/index.html?gnu/trove/map/TCharObjectMap.html) from [Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/)).

  Another idea would be to `keyword`-ify the characters directly (though it would put the burden of filtering unrecognized symbols on the parser).
- `digit?`: `Character/isDigit` does the trick.